# How to make a Unit Test out of a Constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a Unit Test out of a public Constructor.

Using Visual Studio 2012

How can I create a simple Unit Test out of this Constructor.

```
    public ScenarioSelectViewModel(IEventRecorderSvc service)
    {
        eventRecordingSvc = svc;

        OkCmd = new DelegateCommand<Window>(
            OkCmd Executed,
            OkCmd CanExecute);

        RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand = new       DelegateCommand<object>(
            RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommandExecuted,
            RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommandCanExecute);

        if (RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: [Don't perform work in constructors](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple). If you follow that rule, you don't need to test the constructor. Move the work somewhere else where it's contained in a method, and test that method like you'd test any other method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `OkCmd` and `RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand` are publicly exposed properties inyour class ScenarioSelectViewModel.

You are doing 2 things in the constructor which should be tested:

- Okmd and RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand Initialization
- Execution of RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand Command.

You can start asserting the objects that are created, then asserting their publicly exposed properties, i.e. OkCmd.Execute and OkCmd.CanExecute to whatever you are expecting them to be. Same goes with `RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand`.

Then you can assert the execution of the RefreshAvailableScenarioStepExecutionsCommand command